# How to Programmatically Create SDF models/files

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to create SDF files programmatically. The sdformat code has some examples https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat

What is the best way to do this? Is there an example of programmatically generating an SDF?

Is the following the only way to do this?

```
// Set up a simple sdf model file
std::ostringstream stream;
stream << "<sdf version='1.3'>"
       << "<model name='test_model'>"
       << "  <pose>0 1 2  0 0 0</pose>"
       << "  <static>false</static>"
       << "</model>"
       << "</sdf>";
sdf::SDF sdfParsed;
sdfParsed.SetFromString(stream.str());
```

I was thinking something like:

```
sdf::SDFPtr robot(new sdf::SDF());
sdf::init(robot);
robot->root->AddElement("model");
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5228/how-to-programmatically-create-sdf-models/files/) by [isura](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/115/isura/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 55 on 2014-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Both of the examples you gave are valid.

Here is the [API](http://sdformat.org/classsdf_1_1Element.html) for SDF elements.

This [function](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/src/4732294eb7aaccf279a1ae15590ac33e9c6e30d1/src/parser.cc?at=default#cl-429) has many example uses.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1